# How to know which binning mode to apply to target column

Tags: machine-learning, azure-ml

I am trying to prepare for DP-100 certification and I got some sample questions online. Here is one of the questions:

```
You are a data scientist using Azure Machine Learning Studio.
You need to normalize values to produce an output column into bins to predict a target column.
Solution: Apply a Quantiles binning mode with a PQuantile normalization.
Does the solution meet the goal?
A.Yes B.No
Correct Answer: B Section: [none] Explanation
Explanation/Reference: Explanation: Use the Entropy MDL binning mode which has a target column.
References: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/group-data-into-bins
```

I am not really sure why this solution is incorrect. Can someone please tell in what cases we choose which mode?

Comment: Apparently they expect you to use the MDL method because it will create the bins *with respect to the target column* (that is in a supervised way), whereas quantile binning is unsupervised. personally I'm not especially convinced that the normalization should take into account the target column, but why not.

Comment: @Erwan do you think the solution given is absolutely correct? There might be a chance that it is incorrect

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework so I'm not confident enough to say what is correct or incorrect, but from a general ML perspective the explanation that they give is not very convincing: without any additional information about the goal there's no reason to consider quantile normalization as incorrect, so I would say that the question is not clear enough to be answered as a yes/no question.